# D.C. al Fine in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to replicate the following example with D.C. al Fine, the code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.95\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 


\begin{document}
Write the following musical example as it would actually be played without the D.C. al Fine or Fine.\\

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 3/4
    \setlines{1}{1}
    %\hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% i
    \Notes\qu {ii}\en\bar%
    \Notes\ibu0i0\qb0{i}\tbu0\qb0{i}\qu {i}\en\bar%
    \notes\itied0i\hu i\sk\sk\en\bar\setdoubleBAR
    \systemnumbers
    \znotes\ccn{12}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\boxit{\bf $4$}}\en
    \znotes\zcn{q}{\hspace*{+0.3cm}\bf\A Fine}\en
    \notes\ttie0\hu i\sk\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\qp\qu i\en\bar
    \NOtes\qp\qu i\en\bar
    \NOtes\qu i\ibu0i0\qb0{i}\tbu0\qb0{i}\en\bar
    \systemnumbers
    \znotes\ccn{12}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\boxit{\bf $8$}}\en
    \NOTes\qu {ii}\en
    \znotes\ccn{s}{\hspace*{-1.3cm}\bf\A D.C. al Fine}\en
    \setdoublebar\endpiece
 \end{music}
 
 \begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 3/4
    \setlines{1}{1}
    %\hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% i
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar%
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar%
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \systemnumbers
    \znotes\ccn{12}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\boxit{\bf $4$}}\en
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\alaligne\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \systemnumbers
    \znotes\ccn{12}{\hspace*{-1.2cm}\boxit{\bf $8$}}\en
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en
    \setdoublebar\endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is:
[image: current]

The expected output is (note that is needed to configure the Font for D.C al Fine text, and also align the second staff):
[image: expected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.95\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 


\begin{document}
Write the following musical example as it would actually be played without the D.C. al Fine or Fine.\\

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 3/4
    \setlines{1}{1}
    %\hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \parindent0pt
    \startpiece% i
    \Notes\qu {ii}\en\bar%
    \Notes\ibu0i0\qb0{i}\tbu0\qb0{i}\qu {i}\en\bar%
    \notes\itied0i\hu i\sk\sk\en\bar\setdoubleBAR
    \systemnumbers
    \znotes\ccn{12}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\boxit{\bf $4$}}\en
    \znotes\zcn{q}{\hspace*{+0.3cm}\bf\A Fine}\en
    \notes\ttie0\hu i\sk\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\qp\qu i\en\bar
    \NOtes\qp\qu i\en\bar
    \NOtes\qu i\ibu0i0\qb0{i}\tbu0\qb0{i}\en\bar
    \systemnumbers
    \znotes\ccn{12}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\boxit{\bf $8$}}\en
    \NOTes\qu {ii}\en
    \znotes\ccn{s}{\hspace*{-1.3cm}\bf\A D.C. al Fine}\en
    \setdoublebar\endpiece
 \end{music}
 
 \begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 3/4
    \setlines{1}{1}
    %\hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \parindent0pt
    \startpiece% i
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar%
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar%
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \znotes\ccn{12}{\hspace*{-1.1cm}\boxit{\bf 4}}\en
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\alaligne%\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \znotes\ccn{12}{\hspace*{-1.05cm}\boxit{\bf 8}}\en
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en\bar
    \NOtes\sk\en
    \setdoubleBAR\endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follow (note that the letter type for D.C. should be in italics):
[image: output]

Comment: You should add this to the question, not post another question

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.
With `\parindent0pt` you delete the indentation of the first line. You have to write it every time after `\begin{music}`.
Besides `\bf $8$` does not result in a bold 8. If you say `\bf 8`, it does.

Do you want the D.C. al Fine in helvetica italic or do you want the standard music font?